# images sizes, style sheet for mobile devices

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

i am developing app using worklight that needs to fit in for all mobile devices
iphone and android. I am using jquery mobile, css3, html5. 
But when i add header and buttons in header.. they do not resize to mobile height and width(for eg: galaxy s2). either they are large or too small. can anyone pls suggest how i should approach to create a better stylesheet...

Below is the code:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <div style="float:left;width:30%">
        <a data-rel="back" href="" data-role="button" data-theme="none">
            <img class="imgback" src="images/Header_left_btn.PNG" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;width:40%">
        <img src="images/headerText_Lock_icon.PNG" />
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;width:30%">
        <img src="images/logo.PNG" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you provide the screenshot of your device because it may happen in android due to Supports.screens configuration.

Comment: hi.. i cannot take screenshot at the moment..

Comment: Say In your `AndroidManifest.xml` what are the `Supports.screens` configurations.

Comment: <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="false"/>

Comment: give largeScreens True and deploy your application.

Comment: Is this a hybrid Worklight application with environments Android and iPhone? Worklight Skins can be used to support multiple form factors for devices of the same environment.  Please see Worklight V6.1.0 -> Developing IBM Worklight applications -> Artifacts produced during development cycle -> IBM Worklight projects, environments, and skins at https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.doc%2Fwl_home.html

Answer (score 1):

Worklight provides a full tutorial which describes supporting multiple form
factors using Worklight skins. This presentation includes a full tutorial covering what skins are, how skins work as well as an exercise to test what you have learned. The presentation can be found at the following location:

**Using Worklight Skins Presentation:**
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/05_03_Supporting_multiple_form_factors_using_Worklight_skins.pdf